# TFS report that shown iteration id from warehouse

Tags: tfs, parameters, iteration, default

Whenever we start a new iteration I have to set the default value for the iteration parameter in the burndown report (and also other reports). To get the value I follow this instruction (http://salvoz.com/blog/2010/05/04/tfs-2010-default-iteration-and-area-for-burn-down-report/), which includes getting the value with Sql Management Studio connected to the Analysis Service on the tfs data tier. This is becoming increasingly difficult since the number of projects is increasing.

A nicer way to get iteration id's would to get them from a report, whose sole purpose would be to list iterations and show their id's. The report could preferably be installed in the project collection root, i.e. DefaultCollection -folder, and list all iterations for all projects in that collection.

Anyone already have this?

Comment: I am in desperate need of this functionality to allow fellow workers to maintain the sprint reports, and get the weight of this cumbersome effort off my shoulders. @Mathias, shall we try to create such a report ourselves?

Comment: @kroonwijk, I wouldn't mind doing it myself but I'm not familiar enough with Reporting Services and the TFS Warehouse to do this and unfortunately I don't have the time right now to start investigating it. I found this (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ReportingAttributes) but the report I think that the report needs to be installed for a project and not a project collection to work. Maybe someone could just start from Mattias Skölds report?

Comment: Where can I find this report from Mattias Skölds you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link. Here is a blog post (http://mskold.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-change-iteration-for-burn-down.html) and then his report is in his Skydrive (https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5d46cae8c0008cf0&sc=documents&id=5D46CAE8C0008CF0!312). Filename AreasAndIterations.rdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally created a report that lists all iterations in TFS and shows their id and a string that can be pasted directly into the default value for IterationParam for the burn down report.

The report looks like this http://i41.tinypic.com/2qm2bs4.png

The rdl-file that can be installed into Reporting Services can be found [here](http://api2.ge.tt/0/9d6r6ID/0/blob/download). I installed in in the TfsReports-folder that is in the root of Reporting services.

The original sql was found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/tfsreporting/thread/d41c7270-0c2f-4f53-a5bd-d037c7e22b45)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is how [John Socha-Leialoha described using MDX Studio](http://blogs.socha.com/2009/10/customizing-report-parameters-for-team.html) connected up to the OLAP cube for TFS.  Here's where you can download [MDX Studio](http://www.mosha.com/msolap/mdxstudio.htm).

[image: Iteration Nodes in OLAP Cube using MDX Studio]

You essentially end up dragging & dropping the iteration node to the Query Editor so that it will show you the Iteration ID.

[image: Dragging Iteration Node to Query Editor to Get Iteration ID]

Comment: Hi @Ed-Blankenship. This is all clear, as stated in the original question. The problem is that all project owners don't have the tools (nor the knowledge) to get the system iteration id from the warehouse. That's why I would like a report that would list all iteration names and their system id's.

Comment: Is it possible to create a tool for the project owners to use?  That might be a user-friendly way to provide them the information they need.

Comment: That's what I'm proposing in the original question! A report that could be installed in the TFS Reporting Services that shows the technical id for all iterations in all projects in the project collection would be nice.